# Truncate opposite end of string inside html table

Tags: html, css, truncate

Is there a css / html way of truncating the from the start of a string? Showing the end characters instead?

For example:

```
string = "A0000000982091011328885"

truncated (show start) = "A000000098..."
truncated (show end) = "...1011328885"
```

I've tried changing the text `direction` but apart from that I'm out of ideas. I am completely capable of doing this in Javascript however it'd be nice not to.

I'm also doing this within a `table td`, so if there is some weird table specific `<element>` that'd be satisfactory.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/NPrbEQ

Comment: @ArnelleBalane perfect! post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a ["reverse ellipsis" pen](http://codepen.io/kizu/pen/NPrbEQ) made by Roman Komarov which does exactly what you want using just pure CSS. It just requires a specific HTML markup in order to work.

```
<div class="box  ellipsis  reverse-ellipsis">
    <div class="ellipsis__content">Here is some long content that doesn't fit.</div>
</div>
```

It also uses pseudo-elements as the ellipsis and positioned them at the start of the text.

```
.reverse-ellipsis::after {
    content: "…";
    float: left;
    width: 1em;
    padding: 0 1px 0 1em;
    margin: -1.35em -1em;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var rows = document.getElementById('container').childNodes;
for (var i=0, row; row = rows[i]; i++) {
    trimLeft(row);
}

function trimLeft(row){
    var trimContents = function(row, node){
        while (row.scrollWidth > row.offsetWidth) {
            
            var childNode = node.firstChild;
            
            if (!childNode)
                return true;
            
            if (childNode.nodeType == document.TEXT_NODE){
                trimText(row, node, childNode);
            }
            else {
                var empty = trimContents(row, childNode);
                if (empty){
                    node.removeChild(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var trimText = function(row, node, textNode){
        var value = '...' + textNode.nodeValue;
        do {
            value = '...' + value.substr(4);
            textNode.nodeValue = value;
            
            if (value == '...'){
                node.removeChild(textNode);
                return;
            }
        }
        while (row.scrollWidth > row.offsetWidth);
    }

    trimContents(row, row);    
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#container div {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" >
    
    <div>A00000009sfsgsdfggdsf1011328885</div>
   
 </div>
```

Comment: Although it visually places the ellipsis at the start, it still cut's off the end

Comment: I see, however I wanted to avoid javascript - the link @ArnelleBalane provided visually and technically (slightly hacky) without javascript. Thank your for the answer though.